# Elixir/Erlang - Trace when a message arrives in the mailbox

Tags: erlang, elixir, actor, gen-server

Fairly straight forward question, is it possible to trace messages arriving in (the mailbox of) a `Process`/`GenServer`? Note, this is different from tracing when a message is `received` (which would be once it leaves the mailbox and is handled). I've not found a way of doing this until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In erlang you have flags for it in [dbg:p/2](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html#p-2), `s` for sending and `r` for receiving:

```
1> dbg:tracer().
{ok,<0.82.0>}
2> dbg:p(self(), r).
(<0.80.0>) << {dbg,{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,1}]}}
(<0.80.0>) << {io_reply,#Ref<0.2586582558.1779957764.183997>,319}
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,1}]}
(<0.80.0>) << {io_reply,#Ref<0.2586582558.1779957764.184000>,
                        [{expand_fun,#Fun<group.0.82824323>},
                         {echo,true},
                         {binary,false},
                         {encoding,latin1}]}
(<0.80.0>) << {io_reply,#Ref<0.2586582558.1779957764.184002>,ok}
3> self() ! trace_me.
(<0.80.0>) << {shell_cmd,<0.73.0>,
                         {eval,[{op,{1,8},
                                    '!',
                                    {call,{1,1},{atom,{1,1},self},[]},
                                    {atom,{1,10},trace_me}}]},
                         cmd}
(<0.80.0>) << trace_me
(<0.80.0>) << {io_reply,#Ref<0.2586582558.1779957764.184006>,319}
trace_me
(<0.80.0>) << {io_reply,#Ref<0.2586582558.1779957764.184008>,
                        [{expand_fun,#Fun<group.0.82824323>},
                         {echo,true},
                         {binary,false},
                         {encoding,latin1}]}
(<0.80.0>) << {io_reply,#Ref<0.2586582558.1779957764.184011>,ok}
```

Comment: This would be tracing the `receive` (once it leaves the mailbox and is handled), right? I would like to trace the arrival, when it enters the mailbox.

Comment: @Astarno I think that this option traces when the message enters the mailbox: Notice that in the example, the traced process (`self()`, the shell) does not execute a `receive`. As the shell is a little special, I'd verify it with compiled code too, but I don't think there's going to be a difference

Comment: As José says, the receive trace is for when a message is put in the mailbox. There is no way to trace when a message is removed from the mailbox.

Comment: Would there be a way to filter out certain messages (e.g. io_reply)?

Comment: I have something along the lines of `dbg:tracer(process, {fun(Trace, Out) -> dbg:dhandler(Trace, Out) end, standard_io})` to customize the tracing messages in some cases. You'd need to filter out the `Trace` messages you don't want to print, `Trace` messages appear like this: `{trace,pid(),'receive',trace_me}`